# scikit-learn: Why do we need the target data to have the same size with training data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am pretty new to ML and I am studying the k-nearest neighbors classifier using python [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#neighbors)

I am somehow confused about the training part. Let's say my training data is some points in 1d
 `training = [[1], [4], [3]]`
and I want to use k-nearest neighbor classifier to label them into to "teams" :
`labels = [[0], [1]]`
Why does that doesn't make sense ?
I get an error that target values size does not match the input.
If I put instead `labels = [[0], [1], [1]]` or   `labels = [[0], [0], [1]]`
it will compile .
Also a side-note question : does the permutation of labels matter?

Comment: Every point of your training data must have his corresponding label. That's why number of points in the X data and Y data has to match in number of samples. There are plenty of examples on internet. Investigate them. For example this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier) of the library

Comment: so when i call ```fit(X,y)``` is like i am creating a map f of one to one correspondece between X and y? (I could not find online the implementation of ``` fit ``` to understand it better) . Is it like saying ```X[i]``` is categorized as ```y[i]```?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to clusterize your data, which is done by `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors()`. `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()` is a supervized model which requires supplying the actual class for every observation for training and can predict the class for the previously unseen data after that.

However, `NearestNeighbors()` method does not allow to limit the amount of clusters iirc, you should probably try something like `sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2)`.

Comment: So you suggest, that in order to use KNeighborsClassifier I must have a training data set that is labelled , right ? (that's the definition of supervised learning , isn't it?)

Comment: Yes, classification is a supervized technique.